# Asymptotic of Taylor series

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two Taylor series such that:
 $$ f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} a(n) x^{n} $$ and $$ g(x)=
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b(n) x^{n} $$, for $ a(n) >0 $ and $b(n) > 0 $.

My question is, can we extract the asymptotic behavior of these two taylor series for $ x \rightarrow \infty $?

Comment: We have to suppose the radius of convergence to be infinite. What do you exactly mean by asymptotic behavior? What are the properties that interest you?

Answer (score 3):

Asymptotic expansions are essentially different from Taylor and Laurent expansions and cannot be easily deduced from one another. To call an expansion of $f(z)$ as $z\to z_0$ asymptotic you need to find an infinite sequence of functions ${w_n(z)}$ such that $\lim_{z\to z_0}|w_{n+1}(z)/w_n(z)|=0$, or $w_{n+1}=o(w_n(z))$ and obtain expansion of the form
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^Na_nw_n(z)+o(w_N)$$
where coefficients $a_n$ are determined as follows:
$$a_n=\lim_{z\to z_0}\left\{\frac{f(z)-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_n w_n(z)} {w_N(z)}\right\}$$
To get a notion of the difference between the domains where power series converges and an asymptotic expansion is valid, consider the following example.
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-zt}}{1+t^2}dt$$
where $\Re(z)>0$.Expanding the denominator in the geometric series which converges in the circle $|t|<1$ and integrating term by term we obtain:
$$I=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{2!}{z^3}+\frac{4!}{z^5}-...+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-2)!}{z^{2n-1}}+R_n(z)$$
where
$$R_n(z)=(-1)^n\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-zt}t^{2n}}{1+t^2}dt$$
Now 
$$|R_n(z)|\le\int_0^{\infty} e^{-xt}t^{2n}dt=\frac{(2n)!}{x^{2n+1}}$$
Let $z\ne 0$ and $-(\pi/2)+\alpha\le \arg{z}\le (\pi/2)-\alpha$, $0<\alpha<\pi/2$. Then $x\ge \sin\alpha$, hence
$$|R_n(z)|\le\frac{(2n)!}{(\sin\alpha)^{2n+1}}\frac{1}{|z|^{2n+1}}$$
For a fixed $n$, $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}|R_n(z)|=0$. Hence, even that the series does not converge, for *large* $|z|$ and a *finite* number of terms it is a good approximation to the function. In contrast working with power series, for a *given*  $z$ approximation is better, the more terms of the series we take.
The purpose of the example os also to show that whereas Taylor (Laurent) expansion converges within a *circle* (annulus), the domain where asymptotic expansion is valid has the shape of an *angle* in the complex plane.

Comment: no no my comment was a bit different , i mean given a taylor series with infinite radius of convergence so it represents a certain function on the interval $ (0, \infty ) $ obtaine the function $ f(x) $ from its Taylor series

Comment: @Valentin  Would an asymptotic series like this be applicable to [this kind of expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353022/)?