# Approximating definite integral over infinitesimal interval (reformulated)

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, mathematical-physics, perturbation-theory

Pursuant to helpful comments by user254433, I have decided to take another swing at this problem while reformulating it with a simplified example.

**(Reformulated) General Problem:** Generally speaking, I am trying to evaluate a definite integral of the form $\mathcal{I}(L)\equiv \int_0^{L}dy f(y,L) $ in the limit that $L\to 0$ (for $f$ real).  Now, *if* the integrand of interest—and its derivatives in each variable—were finite at the "origin", $|f(0,0)|<\infty$, then I would simply attempt to Taylor expand the integral $\mathcal{I}(L)$ around $L=0$ and apply the ["Leibniz integral rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) as follows,

\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(L) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left. \frac{d^n}{dL^n} \mathcal{I}(L) \right|_{L=0} \frac{L^n}{n!}&\equiv \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[ \frac{d^n}{dL^n} \int_0^L f(y,L)dy \right]_{L=0} \frac{L^n}{n!}\\
&= f(L,L)|_{L=0}L+\left[f^{(0,1)}(L,L)+\frac{1}{2}f^{(1,0)}(L,L)\right]_{L=0}L^2+\mathcal{O}(L^3). \tag{1} \label{1}
\end{align}

However, a naive application of this procedure to my integrand of interest is not possible because it diverges at the origin, $|f(0,0)|=\infty$.  Presumably, I should be applying a different series expansion (is there some Laurent-type expansion for real functions, perhaps?), but I'm not sure which one or how to use it.  [Maybe I need an ["asymptotic expansion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion)?  I really don't know what I should be doing here.]

**Explicit (Simplified) Example:** Consider the following (highly simplified) example integrand which diverges at the origin: $f(y,L)=y/L^2$.  Now, for this example, it would be trivial to directly integrate $f$ over $y:[0,L]$ to obtain $\mathcal{I}(L)$=1/2, which is, moreover, independent of $L$, rendering the $L\to 0$ limit irrelevant.  However, my actual integrand of interest involves a product of Bessel functions which I cannot directly integrate for finite, nonzero $L$.

**Question:** Ignoring the fact that this toy integrand can be directly integrated, how would one go about expanding $\mathcal{I}(L)$ around $L=0$ in this case?  [Or if this toy integrand proves to be too trivial to illustrate the procedure, how would one go about expanding an integrand of your choice which also diverges in some way that would make a naive application of Taylor unworkable?]

Comment: Have you tried not expanding the propagator in $y$, and just expanding the definite integral in $L$?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean.  Do you mean expand the integrand around $L=0$ only?  Two issues with that: 1) The integrand is nonsingular on the integration interval $y:[0,L]$ only for $L>0$.  If I expand around $L=0$ prior to integration then I pick up a singularity at $y=0$.  2) I don't understand the logic of a procedure where I would be taking $L\to 0$ *prior* to integrating from $0$ to $L$.  Maybe this would make sense by taking the integration over $[\epsilon,L]$ and then taking $L \to \epsilon \to 0$ or something?  But I'd need more help to understand that.

Comment: @user254433 I was probably mistaken before.  It seems more likely that you meant I should Taylor expand the definite integral in $L$ and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.  I will have to give this a look.

Comment: There are some terms missing in your expansion.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule  for what I mean by differentiating the definite integral in $L$.

Comment: @user254433  you are right; sorry for the error.   Hopefully, I now have the correct expansion up to third order in $L$.  I don't yet see how to address my previous issues at first order in $L$, though.

Comment: @user254433   Making use of your corrections, I have reformulated the question in a way which may make my precise difficulty more transparent.